# Find points within a box bound using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, google-maps-api

I'm trying to use PostgreSQL and PostGIS to return locations within a specific box bound.

Example

- User has a map view on Google Maps
- Google API returns box bounds using `map.getBounds()` - in my specific issue, the bounds from google maps are

  ```
  north: "51.52070000000002", 
  south: "51.52070000000002", 
  west: "-0.13450000000000184", 
  east: "-0.13450000000000184"
  ```

  and I'm using `ST_MakeEnvelope()` like so:

  ```
  ST_MakeEnvelope(-0.13450000000000184, 51.52070000000002, 
                  -0.13450000000000184, 51.52070000000002, 
                  4326)
  ```
- I have a locations table in my db with columns longitude, latitude and geom where geom is indexed with GIST and created by `ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude::numeric,latitude::numeric), 4326);`
- The SQL query just to sense check is

  ```
  select geom && ST_MakeEnvelope(-0.13450000000000184, 51.52070000000002, 
                                 -0.13450000000000184, 51.52070000000002, 
                                 4326)
  ```

  where geom is `SRID=4326;POINT(-0.1309 51.5162)` and which should return true but returns false instead
- I also had this query

  ```
  SELECT   id,     
           ST_Y(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude)) AS y,
           ST_X(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude)) AS x 
  FROM     map_locations ml
  WHERE    ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeBox2D(ST_Point(latitude, longitude), 
                                   ST_Point(longitude, latitude) ),          
                      4326)  
        && ST_MakeEnvelope(-0.13450000000000184, 51.52070000000002, 
                           -0.13450000000000184, 51.52070000000002, 
                           4326)
  ```

  but these created box bounds in the incorrect places.
- I also tried `ST_WITHIN()` and `ST_CONTAINS()` with the same result

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you look at the coordinates of what you get with getBounds you'll notice that they do not make a box but a point.

Comment: -0.33 does not fall between -0.13 and -0.13

Comment: I also had this query `SELECT
 id,
 ST_Y(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude)) AS y,
 ST_X(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude)) AS x
FROM
 map_locations ml
WHERE
 ST_SetSRID(
        ST_MakeBox2D(
            ST_Point(latitude, longitude), ST_Point(longitude, latitude)
        ), 
        4326
    )
 && ST_MakeEnvelope(-0.13450000000000184, 51.52070000000002, -0.13450000000000184, 51.52070000000002, 4326)` but these created box bounds in the incorrect places. I also tried ST_WITHIN and ST_CONTAINS with the same result

Answer (score 2):

I formatted the question body to make this a bit more visible: the coordinates you said you got from `map.getBounds()` make up a box with *zero area* - it's effectively a point, as immediately pointed out by [@user30184](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/478990/find-points-within-a-box-bound-using-postgis#comment781429_478990).

For that to match with `&&`, the `geom` in your `map_locations` would have to happen to be that exact same point, a line (more or less) running through it, a polygon that covers that spot or a collection that includes one of those.

---

That `ST_MakeBox2D()` could cover 12.5%-25% of the surface of the globe in some cases:

```
ST_MakeBox2D(ST_Point(latitude, longitude), 
             ST_Point(longitude, latitude) )
```

`ST_Point()` accepts lon/lat:

> `geometry ST_Point(float x, float y);`
> …
> For geodetic coordinates, `X` is longitude and `Y` is latitude

[So on the North Pole:](https://dbfiddle.uk/eT1W8tln)

```
with cte as (select st_setsrid(ST_MakeBox2D(ST_Point(90,0),
                                            ST_Point(0,90)),
                               4326) AS geom )
select st_astext(geom),
       st_area(st_transform(geom,3857)) as area_in_3857,
       st_area(geom::geography(Polygon,4326)) as area_as_geography
from cte;
```

| st_astext | area_in_3857 | area_as_geography |
| --- | --- | --- |
| POLYGON((0 0,0 90,90 90,90 0,0 0)) | 2.429835233887958e+15 | 63758202715511.07 |

It still won't necessarily `&&` with your geom, and if it does, I'm not sure that's really what you wanted to find.

Comment: Thanks for answering! and your point about the `getBounds()` makes sense. With this then, how would i go about finding those matching locations within the coordinates that i get back from the `getBounds` function?

Comment: @KennSeangpachareonsub My guess would be that you accidentally called `.getNorthEast()` twice (or `.getSouthWest()` twice) on the `LatLngBounds` you got from `getBounds()`, which is why you get the same lat/lon - could be something else, but you're not showing that part of your solution. If you fix how you get the bounds so that you don't re-use one corner, you'll get different points, which will let you construct a non-zero-area box/envelope. Then a `&&` or `st_intersects()` will be able to find whatever you got in that area.

Comment: If for some reason you can't fix `.getBounds()` getting you the same corner twice, you'll have to figure out whether that's the NE or SW and I guess you could reconstruct the bounds by generating the other corner by shifting the one you have by `.getZoom()`. Problem is, things like this or `ST_Expand()`ing around the one point you have might result in not quite the same bounds, hence not quite the same shapes getting caught by the subsequent `&&`. Plus, that's patching a bug you probably could remove at the source, by figuring out why you're getting just one corner from `.getBounds()`.

Comment: If you make sure you're not re-using a corner, then maybe `.setZoom()` was too high, or you're making the bounds dependent on a set of points containing just a single point, [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11454897/5298879). I'm not sure max zoom would result in zero-area bounds, though.

Comment: thanks for all this, actually ended up figuring it out a minute a go. For some reason getBounds returns the same corner for the west and east coordinates. Doing getBounds().getSouthWest() and .getNorthEast() ended up doing the job and returned different values for all 4 corners